# How to print a message if input does not match data in CSV?

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

This is my code that runs:

```
import csv

#input name you want to search
name = input('Enter name to find\n')

#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('test.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")

#loop through the csv list
for row in csv_file:
        #if current rows 1st value is equal to input, print 2nd value
    if (name == row[0]):
        print (row[1])
        #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print 1st value
    if (name == row[1]):
        print (row[0])
```

I can't add

```
else:
    print("invalid input")
```

after the two `if` because it will print tons of it as it loops thru the whole CSV file.

Also, I have tried to add the following codes outside of the `for`, but the invalid message will still print even the input matches the CVS file

```
if (name not in csv_file):
    print("invalid input")
```

Comment: Can you explain better? Do you want to print _all_ lines where `name in row[0]` or `name in row[1]` is true but if _no_ lines have `name` then `print("invalid input")`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if name doesn't match anything in the CSV file, then  `print("invalid input")`

Answer (score 0):

Break out of the loop if you find a match. Then use `else:` on the `for` statement to execute code if the loop finishes without breaking.

```
for row in csv_file:
        #if current rows 1st value is equal to input, print 2nd value
    if (name == row[0]):
        print (row[1])
        break
        #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print 1st value
    if (name == row[1]):
        print (row[0])
        break
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: I just tested it and it worked.

Comment: Make sure you indent it correctly. `else:` should be at the same indentation as `for`, not `if`.